# Div that flexible by content, but stretched by body tag (height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div container, stretched vertically to 'body'.

Inside it I have 2 DIVs on the one level.

- The 1st must be stretched to browser's window. But it minimal
  height shouldn't be smaller, than the second's height.
- The 2nd have 2 fixed heights (changing by JS).

The problem is:
[image]

Can I solve this problem WITHOUT using JS, but only with CSS+HTML?

**UPDATE:**

[My HTML code structure - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3wj6q7k/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>

.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 51px;    
}

.div1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -51px;
    background: red;
}

.div2{
    float: left;
    width: 440px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 44px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: please provide your css and html code thanks!

Comment: It seems that your "jsFiddle example" links to an image. We'll need to see your relevant code.

Comment: @showdev, sorry, corrected :)

Comment: Your code should be in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first `<div>` to *always* be at least as tall as the second `<div>`, I would start by placing the latter inside the former:

```
<div class="div1">

<div class="div2"></div>

</div>
```